# How to install Neatx-Server on ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, apt, neatx

After try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/ppa && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team<br>
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team
```

None can let the `sudo apt-get update` to be succeed.
Not to mention `sudo apt-get install neatx-server`. (found no neatx-server)

Is there a solution for that?
thanks~

Comment: meaning you cant do update after? is their PPA up? perhaps it is down?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `neatx-server` on the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~freenx-team/+archive/ppa) that you are trying to add. Maybe it is bundled with `neatx`